# C# Store function dictionary dataset

Tags: c#, .net, function, dictionary, dataset

Should call the function and return the dataset but it doesn't. There's no error when I debug.

I evaluated the  "queryFunc"  and shows " {Method = {System.Data.DataSet EqpSizeGetAll()}} "

Instead of my dataset with the information.

Here is my code:

```
 public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string SearchField { get; set; }
    public string EntityType { get; set; }

    private static readonly IDictionary<string, Func<DataSet>> typeaheads =
        new Dictionary<string, Func<DataSet>>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        {
            { "EqpSize", EqpSizeGetAll }
        };

    //private static readonly IDictionary<string, string> dem = new Dictionary<string, string>()

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Func<DataSet> queryFunc;

        if (typeaheads.TryGetValue(EntityType, out queryFunc))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                plhEntity.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Format("<Label><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"{0}\">Dry Van {1}</Label>", SearchField, i))); //<br/>
            }    
        }
    }

    private static DataSet EqpSizeGetAll()
    {
        var demo = "asdas";
        string asd = demo;
        return BusinessFacadesFactory.CreateBusinessFacade<BFEqpSize>().GetAll(); 
    }
```

Comment: The code you provided doesn't call `queryFunc`. It should look like `queryFunc()` or `queryFunc.Invoke()` - but neither of those are in the code that you've given.

Comment: You're right. I forgot to update this post but the answer you give me that is call to invoke() is what I missed. Thanks for your help!